# Careers: edit CV, 'see a live preview' not working or not yet implemented?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Is it just me?

When I click on 'see a live preview', nothing happens.

And also, as of today, whatever I change, the Save button doesn't get enabled.

(Firefox 3.0.15 on Windows XP SP3)

Comment: This should be resolved - we've switched to WMD to render markdown using javascription on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with our build - the cache breakers for client scripts aren't being appended to our javascript files.

Working on that now.

In the meantime, if you do a hard refresh of the page (or clear your cache for Careers), you should get the latest files.

Comment: OK, I did Ctrl-F5, the link works, but I just get the 'generating preview' text, and nothing more. I'll let you finish though ;)